# I want one input field's value to be equal to another input field at all times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checkbox for setting a billing address to the mailing address, so if the checkbox is checked, the two values will always be the same, even if one changes. As of now, I can get the billing address to copy the mailing address once the box is checked, but if you change the values afterwards, the view is not updated. Here is what I have so far:

**createcustomer.html:**

```
<section class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="createcustomer as vm">
<div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="txtMailingAddress1">Address 1:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" id="txtMailingAddress1" name="txtMailingAddress1" value="" data-ng-model="vm.MailingAddress1" class="form-control FloatLeft" required />
                        </div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSameAddress" data-ng-model="vm.IsBillingMailing" data-ng-change="vm.copyMailingAddress()" />Check if billing address same as mailing address

<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="txtBillingAddress1">Address 1:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" id="txtBillingAddress1" name="txtBillingAddress1" data-ng-model="vm.BillingAddress1" class="form-control FloatLeft" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</section>
```

**createcustomer.js**

```
function copyMailingAddress() {
            if (vm.IsBillingMailing) {
                vm.BillingAddress1 = vm.MailingAddress1;
            }
            else {
                vm.BillingAddress1 = '';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going about it all wrong.  You need to apply some Angular.  Here is one way to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RpfNd/

```
var app = angular.module('shippingApp', []);

app.controller('ShippingCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.mailing = {
        first: 'Jon',
        last: 'Doe',
        address1: '123 Main Street'
    };
    $scope.billing = {};
    $scope.billing_same = false;

    $scope.$watch('billing_same',function(same_as_shipping) {
        if (same_as_shipping) {
            $scope.billing = $scope.mailing;
        }
        else {
            $scope.billing = {};   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Didn't realise question was related to angularjs. Not stated in title or question. Noticed tags after comment below. Mods please remove this answer if it's useless for this page. Thanks**

----------Original answer-------------

Easier solution (what I seem to use maybe out of laziness) and it's also more safe from errors in my opinion.

If "Use same as mailing address" is checked then disable all the billing address fields with javascript/jQuery

Then when form is posted, validate it thus (assuming you're using php):

```
if(isset($_POST['checkboxSameAddress'])){
    $txtBillingAddress1 = $txtMailingAddress1;
    $txtBillingAddress2 = $txtMailingAddress2;
    //and so on
}
```

This way you're guaranteed the values are identical without manipulating so much with jQuery/Javascript

Note: Input checkbox will require the `name` attribute for this to work

Comment: -1 php has no value in a javascript framework that has internal data binding

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't realise the angularjs tag. Questioner didn't state it in question or title